# Pandas Groupby and applying ROC_AUC_SCORE error

Tags: python, pandas, roc

I have a Pandas DF like:

```
id  data1 data2 ... dataN score1 score2 ... scoreM  target 
1   1     0     ... 1     0.21.  0.64   ... 0.34    1
```

I want to group this dataframe by ['data1',....'dataM'] and see on each split the ROC AUC SCORE of each score. Checking some previous answers here i thought doing something like this:

```
def auc_group(df):
y_hat = df.target_fpd
y = df.score
return roc_auc_score(y_hat, y)


group_dict = {}

for sc in list_scores:
    df_it = df_all[['target',sc,'data1','data2','data3','data4','data5']]
    df_it = df_it.rename(columns={sc:'score'})
    g[sc] = df_it.groupby(['data1','data2','data3','data4','data5']).apply(auc_group)
```

Then I could have each on a dictionary g and could work from that by merging them.
The problem is that not every combination of datai is balanced towards target so there are certain splits which cant be done and i get the error:

```
ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case.
```

How can i bypass that error and replace it with 0 when that happens?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer already. Instead of applying the function after the groupby, its better to save the groupby and then iterate over the splits using try/except.

the resulting code would be:

```
grouping = df_all.groupby(['data1','data2','data3','data4','data5'])
group_dict = {}
for i in grouping: 
    (group_label, df) = i
    roc=[]
    for sc in list_scores:
            try:
                roc.append(roc_auc_score(df.target,df[sc]))
            except :
                roc.append(0)
     group_dict[group_label] = pd.DataFrame({'scores':list_scores,'rocs':roc})
```

If anyone has a simpler way i'd love to hear it!